# Inline CSS stripped from email

Tags: css, email

From emails that I send (using Gmail's mail server), Yahoo manipulates inline CSS.

This is the original style I applied (as inline):

```
background: rgb(248, 204, 204) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
```

But what I see in the email (Yahoo inbox) is this:

```
background: rgb(248, 204, 204) none repeat scroll 0% 0% auto
```

Why does this happen, and how can I avoid this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This link might be helpful to you - http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/yahoo_betas_embedded_css_may_affect_your_layout

Comment: It happens so that your incoming emails don't break the Yahoo mail page. I doubt you can stop it. If it's important, generate emails that don't include styling that's stripped by Yahoo.

Comment: @NathanLee But the article tells me to use inline CSS, as a solution, which I already am

Comment: @MikeW Is there a tool or something that I can use to generate such styles?

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't know.

Comment: Yes, but there is a stack overflow link in the same that tells you that certain css properties, especially shorthand properties does not effectively work on yahoo. - @th3an0maly

Comment: @NathanLee Actually, that explains it. I just removed my shorthand properties and it worked. Not only does Yahoo remove the shorthand properties, it selectively chooses certain properties (like `auto` in my case), which makes the style value invalid. Still no idea *why*

Comment: @NathanLee You could post it as an answer and I could accept it :)

Comment: Added the answer below. - @th3an0maly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo ignores certain css properties, especially css shorthand properties, that works on browsers and other email clients, but not effectively on yahoo.

Under such cases, you need to convert the shorthand properties into expanded properties for them to work on yahoo.

You can read the below link to get further details for the same.

http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/yahoo_betas_embedded_css_may_affect_your_layout

Hope this helps.

Comment: [Full CSS guide](http://campaignmonitor.cachefly.net/assets/files/css/campaign-monitor-guide-to-css-in-email-sep-2013V2.pdf?ver=1322) from Campaign Monitor